# how to change a wordpress home page permalink as referenced in submenu links

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, submenu

I have a wordpress website with a menu structure that has home page as a parent with two sub-menus: privacy & sitemap.

The Permalink for the home page is this:

http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/ (as you would expect - since wordpress doesn't display the home page name.)

But for the two sub-menus it shows up as this:

http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home-2/privacy-statement/

http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home-2/site-map/

Why is the home page now listed as **home-2** directory? Where can I change it back to be just **home**?

If I actually put this in the address bar:
http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home/site-map/
It resolves to this:
http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home-2/site-map/

I don’t think this was the way it worked when I first started this site. However, I accidentally deleted my main menu at some point (I know.. my bad!), and had to re-add the menu. It was after this event that I noticed the **home-2** in the URLS. (This probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but I wanted to mention it just in case!)

I also read somewhere that if you have a duplicate page name (ie: in draft) that will cause the -2 added to a directory or page name.  I did have a duplicate home (draft) page, but I have now trashed it & permanently removed it, AND that still didn't solve my problem.

What is causing it to be **home-2**, and is there anyway I can change it back to **home**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `All pages` from `Dashboard` and find the parent page of your subpages `site-map` and `privacy-statement`. It must be named `Home`( your front page now ). Then hover on it and click `Quick Edit`.

You should saw something like this: [image: screen]

Change the `slug` from `home-2` to `home`( I marked that field with red underline ). And click to `Update` button. Your subpages will have permalinks like so now:
`http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home/privacy-statement/`
`http://localhost/mysite/mysiteWP/home/site-map/`

*Note, that you can't save page with slug `home`, if there is another page with same `slug` in the `Published`, `Draft`, `Scheduled` categories.*